# Application Pool goes IDLE with startMode = AlwaysRunning

Tags: iis

As far as I know the IDLE timeout will only be effective when `startMode=OnDemand`, however I found the following message in event log:

```
A worker process with process id of '2556' serving application pool 'xxxx' was shutdown due to inactivity.  Application Pool timeout configuration was set to 20 minutes.  A new worker process will be started when needed.
```

I've set the timeout to 5 minutes to help me found out the target setting, it seems the IDLE timer is still effective while `startMode=AlwaysRunning`.

I also found that a new worker process of that application pool is immediately started, however I was expecting that the application pool will not recycle every 5 minutes. Anyone know whats happening?

Comment: Have you set `autoStart` to `true`?

Comment: Yes, also I have a WCF service within that application pool, I notice that every time  when the IDLE timer reaches zero, Application_start of the web service will be called. My guess is that every time the IDLE timer reaches zero, IIS automatically start a new application pool and init all my web service again..